# Why does my Grpc ClientInterceptor not have the right reactor Context?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, grpc-java

I'm trying to understand the reactor Context and why I'm getting this error:

> reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Context does not contain key

I have a WebFilter that writes some context

```
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
  return chain.filter(exchange)
      .contextWrite(Context.of("CONTEXT-HEADER", "foobar"));
}
```

I have a ClientInterceptor that tries to read it

```
public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method, CallOptions callOptions, Channel next) {
  final ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> call = next.newCall(method, callOptions);

  return new ForwardingClientCall.SimpleForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT>(call) {
    @Override
    public void start(Listener<RespT> responseListener, Metadata headers) {

      Mono.deferContextual(context -> {
        Metadata.Key < String > key =
            Metadata.Key.of("CONTEXT-HEADER", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
        headers.put(key, context.get("CONTEXT-HEADER"));

        delegate().start(responseListener, headers);

        return Mono.empty();
      }).subscribe();


    }
  };
}
```

In case it matters, I add this interceptor when I create the grpc stub.

```
MyServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel).withInterceptors(new MyClientInterceptor());
```

And my grpc call is done from the Controller method

```
@GetMapping(path="test")
public Mono<String> test() {
  return Mono.just(grpcStub.call(RequestBuilder.build()));
}
```

I'm getting the error above on the `context.get("CONTEXT-HEADER")` call.
I should note that the same code to get the header from the Context works fine when invoked in the Controller method. But it the reactor pipeline seems to break at some point after calling the grpc method which invokes the ClientInterceptor

What causes the reactor chain to be broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reactor context is propagated through subscriptions chain, from bottom to the top.

Subscription starts from the bottom, and at every step subscriber gives its current context to the publisher. On the next step publisher becomes a subscriber and propagate context to the next publisher, etc. See `reactor.core.CorePubliser` and `reactor.core.CoreSubscriber` and [reactor context docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context).

For example in the following chain

```
1: Mono.just(...);
2:     .flatMap(
           ... 
3:         Mono.just(...).subscribe()
           ...
         )
4:     .contextWrite(...);
5:     .flatMap(...);
6:     .subscribe();
```

Reactor operators incapsulate Publisher and Subscriber from reactive-streams.

Operator at line 1 is a publisher, at 6 is a subscriber and operators at lines 2,4,5 are both.

Context is empty at lines 5,6; populated at line 4, and contains operators at 1 and 2 can consume populated context.

Line 3 can't see context, because context "doesn't subscribe" to it. Even though it is inside an operator, that can access context.

In your interceptor is like line 3, you subscribe 'manually' and your subscription just doesn't have any context.

```java
Mono.deferContextual(context -> {
        Metadata.Key < String > key =
            Metadata.Key.of("CONTEXT-HEADER", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
        headers.put(key, context.get("CONTEXT-HEADER"));

        delegate().start(responseListener, headers);

        return Mono.empty();
      }).subscribe();
```

I don't know of any 'out-of-the-box' interceptors that can access reactor context, but you can try to do manual wiring between reactor Context and grpc Context before calling a stub. This [integration tests in reactive-grpc](https://github.com/salesforce/reactive-grpc/blob/master/reactor/reactor-grpc-test/src/test/java/com/salesforce/reactorgrpc/ContextPropagationIntegrationTest.java) may give an example of using grpc Context.

Comment: I think that's a good explanation. Thank you for simplifying my example and showing me where the issue is